# PDFMiner returns wrong RGB color and also returns INT value 0 or 1

Tags: python, pdfminer, pdf-parsing, pdfminersix

LTTextHorizontal for this object.

When I iterate over LTChar in this way.
char.graphicstate.ncolor it returns wrong RGB values when it is white it returns (1,1,1) and for other pdf it returns 0 or 1.

How can this be fixed?

```
for page_layout in extract_pages(scr_file):
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                fontinfo = set()
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            fontinfo.add(character.fontname)
                            fontinfo.add(character.size)
                            fontinfo.add(character.graphicstate.scolor)
                            fontinfo.add(character.graphicstate[text]([https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com))
```

Answer (score 0):

Colors in PDFs are floats running from 0 to 1, not integers from 0 to 255 as you seem to expect.